# Handle onClick of Asp:CheckBoxList ONLY if Checked in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick, checkboxlist

I have a asp.net checkbox list that is dynamically generated and I need to process some code if the checkbox was initially checked and is unchecked.

This needs to be done in Jquery or Javascript.

All the examples I see deal with getting all values of "Checked" I am only interested in getting the specific item that triggered the onClick() event's ID so that I can run some other code to process it.

```
public void DrawPoolWeekCbList()
{
    var poolWeeks = ControllerFacade.GetAllPoolWeeksByPoolYear(PageView.PoolWeekYear.Text);
    var pWeekCount = poolWeeks.Count;
    var curRecord = 0;
    foreach (var poolWeek in poolWeeks)
    {
        PageView.cblPoolWeeks.Items.Add(poolWeek);
        PageView.cblPoolWeeks.Items[curRecord].Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnCheckBoxClicked("+ poolWeek +")");
        curRecord++;
    }
}

//UI Code
function OnCheckBoxClicked(poolWeek) {
    var chkId = poolWeek.toString();
    $('#<%= lblPoolWeekChange.ClientID %>').text(chkId);
    $(".addNew").dialog("open");
}
```

All the samples I have seen find ALL checked checkboxes and loop through them all, again I just want the SPECIFIC checkboxes id that triggered the function.

Thanks!

```
//Generated HTML - 
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblPoolWeeks_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblPoolWeeks$0" onclick="OnCheckBoxClicked(01);" value="01" /><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblPoolWeeks_0">01</label></td><td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblPoolWeeks_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblPoolWeeks$1" onclick="OnCheckBoxClicked(02);" value="02" /><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblPoolWeeks_1">02</label></td><td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblPoolWeeks_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblPoolWeeks$2" onclick="OnCheckBoxClicked(03);" value="03" /><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblPoolWeeks_2">03</label>
```

Comment: Can you show html generated by your code? did your code call OncheckBoxClicked?

Comment: Where is the code that creates/adds the checkbox? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet worked for me, keep in mind there is only one CheckBoxList on the asp.net page, if there was more than one this might not work - Keep in mind this is for handling a SINGLE checkbox and not for iterating through as in "CHECK ALL" functionality. This is handy if you need to add all checked values to a session variable(My case) for a later update of the records.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
           if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
               OnCheckBoxClicked(this.value);
           } else {
               OnUnchecked(this.value);
           }
       });
   }); 

   function OnCheckBoxClicked(poolWeek) {

       var chkId = poolWeek.toString();
       //Show DialogBox - Set label to pool week.
       $('#<%= lblPoolWeekChange.ClientID %>').text(chkId);
       $(".addNew").dialog("open");

   }

   function OnUnchecked(poolWeek) {
       var chkId = poolWeek.substring(2, 4);
       var commodity = $('#<%= Commodity.ClientID %> option:selected').text();
       $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Ajax/DeleteExcludedPoolWeek.aspx",
                    data: "poolWeek=" + chkId +  "&commodity=" + commodity,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $('#myDiv').text('Pool week status changed.');

                    },
                    error: function (x, e) {
                        alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                    }
                }
            );
   }
```